# How to show the coordinate of certain points on the axes of a graph?

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates

Here is the code I want to extend

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xticklabel={\hour:\minute},
xticklabel style =
{rotate=45,anchor=near xticklabel},
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin={2020-04-04 10:00},
xmax={2020-04-04 11:30},
]
\addplot[color=yellow, mark=square] coordinates {
(2020-04-04 10:00, 0)
(2020-04-04 10:30, 25)
(2020-04-04 10:40, 28)
(2020-04-04 11:00, 40)
(2020-04-04 11:15, 42)
(2020-04-04 11:30, 50)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to show the coordinates of the square coordinates **on the axes** like this:

[image]

How do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does what you want in principle, I think. However, to get a pleasing result one would have to decide on how to arrange the labels.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,
indicate coordinates/.style={scatter,
/pgfplots/date coordinates default inverse={x}{\hour:\minute},
scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={%
\coordinate (tmp);
\draw[dashed,gray] (tmp|-current axis.south) 
node[rotate=45,anchor=north east] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}}
|- (tmp-|current axis.west) node[left] {\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}%
\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult};
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits,
width=14cm,
date coordinates in=x,
xticklabel={\hour:\minute},
xticklabel style =
{rotate=45,anchor=near xticklabel},
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin={2020-04-04 10:00},
xmax={2020-04-04 11:30},
]
\addplot[color=yellow, mark=square,indicate coordinates] coordinates {
(2020-04-04 10:00, 0)
(2020-04-04 10:30, 25)
(2020-04-04 10:40, 28)
(2020-04-04 11:00, 40)
(2020-04-04 11:15, 42)
(2020-04-04 11:30, 50)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to actually show the time (e.g. 10:40) on the labels? Because the dates weren't really meant to show, as they are all the same.

Comment: @BookOfFlames Sure, I made the changes accordingly by adding `/pgfplots/date coordinates default inverse={x}{\hour:\minute},`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @user241086